# Does this simple service catalog + rest api product I'm looking for exist?

Tags: product

I work a devops-ish position in a healthcare company and I need some help figuring out if the solution I'm looking for exists. Today we use ServiceNow and their Service Portal product. When a user requests something it, it triggers a flow in ServiceNow that eventually fires off a REST call to our automation suite.

Our automation suite is just fine, but we've found that the model of creating these interactions in ServiceNow's flow designer is a nightmare, and we have a team that is absolutely resource starved and can hardly support us. They gave us access to flow designer, and any time we need something changed we have to relearn a really complicated process to make something. This model is not sustainable if we want to bring more teams along with us. Our team is filled with people that learn fast, and can design these 'forms' and 'workflows', but I wouldn't expect some of our other teams to be able to and we want them to be able to offer a catalog of items they support.

My ideal workflow in the product looks something like this:

1. Design form/catalog item as code. HTML?
2. Easily import into **product** git? copy paste? whatever? The important part here is that it is easy. No hooks into 15 databases, no certification required to know how to make it. Ability to add labels, dropdowns, text fields, whatever. Basic objects users are used to interacting with.
3. Now that your form is designed, in this example lets pretend it's a server. The user visits the portal, types in/sees the "server" item. They specify RAM/CPU/Disk/OS/hostname/whatever. They hit submit and now they are done interacting with it.
4. **product** now sends a simple json payload of what the user selected on the forum to an appropriate API integration.
5. User gets their thing.

Easy, right? Authentication/approval would be a big plus, but we've already built systems for that that don't need to rely on the portal.

This all sounds like ServiceNow, but their model of creating catalog items and workflows just doesn't scale with what we have available to us, and it feels really convoluted any time I have to go in and change even one dropdown on a form. I LOVE ServiceNow and wanted so badly to be able to support using their platform as our service portal, but unless we've been using it wrong and their salesfolk are doing a bad job, it's not the solution for us. We do have the resources to build this ourselves, but I don't want to write ServicePortal.js if what I described exists.